# Can I have a body apply to a different page than the current content type?

Tags: views, nodes, wysiwyg

I want to give the editor user a good experience where he/she can edit everything about one news article in one content type. I have a gallery that takes a content type where he/she can place an image, caption, and a link. I desire this link to be pointing to the page where the body wysiwyg would be. I would like the body to be in the same content type, just displayed on a different page.
I hope I am clear. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you are asking, but I will try to help anyway (and maybe with more clarification I can help further)).

It sounds like you have a gallery content type. Do you need these gallery images for anything else? Because it also sounds like you want an image to show up on the news article page. If that is the case, why not just have fields for the images, caption, and link in the news article content type? That way, when the person goes to edit the news article, everything is write there - both the fields related to the news article itself as well as the fields related to the gallery ones. I feel like this would make more sense to the person editing it anyway.

And then if you still need a separate gallery or something using the images that have been added, you can still use the images in the news article content type to make a separate view.

Comment: I think I can see what you are saying. I can put everything in one content type. Though, one thing remains. How do I get the computer to link to the news article from the views slider? (My gallery is in fact a slide show)

Comment: You can have that field link to the original content, which should be somewhere in the settings for the field.


That MIGHT just be for titles though, and if that is so, add the Link field to the view, add the field that you want to be a link before it and hide it from display, then rewrite the results of Link to be the previous field.


I think that's clear, but if not I can take more time to look at it and tell you exactly what would have to be done.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. I don't have enough time to go test this out, as I am in another project now, but this does seem to be the answer.  Thanks! I will probably get to it around the time I get enough reputation to up vote your answer. When that time comes I'll give more points if everything works right.